# Software Defined Storage (SDS): How to choose right moment to lock it for backing up?

Tags: client-server, storage

I'm developing a server which provides a virtual block device via SCSI interface. The device is constantly bombarded by requests to read/write data blocks. Sometimes I need to lock this device (or make it read only) just to perform some device-wide operations on it - for example, a full backup.

I worry about incomplete transactions, which might be broken in the middle by such locking. For example, let's assume that the block device has been formatted as a filesystem - then such a potentially incomplete transaction might be saving a file + updating a directory, containing this file. I don't see *anything in the SCSI interface*, which could help me to choose a right moment to lock my block device, and it's understandable because block operations and file operations belong to different software layers.

Are there any state-of-the-art methods which can solve this problem?

Comment: Have you heard of [hot swap raid 5](https://www.qnap.com/en-us/tutorial/con_show.php?op=showone&cid=38)?

Comment: @CandiedOrange - yes, I have, but I don't see how it could help me

Comment: You might want to take a look at databases and filesystems to see how they implement transactions. A filesystem should always be in a valid state even when the device is suddenly disconnected. AFAIK this can be done by writing changes to a journal first, then writing updated blocks to a free location, then atomically updating pointers from the old blocks to the new blocks and marking the transaction as complete. Combined with mirrored storage, that would allow you to switch one partition to read-only at any point in time and still have valid data.

Comment: @amon - thank you, it makes sense but looks really complex. I hoped to get away with some manipulations on the SCSI level. Like with traffic lights - to switch from green to red via intermediate yellow